# Laravel: return specific relation data

Tags: laravel

I have the following laravel method:

```
 public function getTeam()
    {
        $userCharacters = UserCharacters::with('evolution')
        ->where('user_id','=',$this->id);

        return $userCharacters->get();
    }
```

As you can see:

- every user has characters, described in the **UserCharacters** Model.
- each character has an evolution (I linked it with the user character itself too).

What I need is to return **only** the evolutions where the evolution `level` field is **smaller or equals**  to the user character level.

Currently, It returns all evolution, regard of the level.

I've been trying to add this `where` condition in the relation `evolution()` in the `UserCharacters` Model, but it doesn't work with the Laravel `With`:

```
public function evolution()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Evolution::class,"character_id")->where('level','<',$this->level);
}
```

Hope someone can help me with this, Thanks!

Comment: Probably `$this->level` is not set yet when you call `UserCharacters::with('evolution')`. What does `dd(UserCharacters::with('evolution')->toSql());` return?

Comment: Returns `"select * from user_characters"`

Comment: I'm a bit confused.. Try this: `where('level', '<', 'user_characters.level')`

Answer (score 0):

Try the query builder. As "$this->id" must return the user id, you should call this from the user model):

```
public function getTeam()
{
    return DB::table('user_characters')
    ->join('evolutions','user_characters.id','=','evolutions.user_characters_id')
    ->where('user_characters.user_id','=',$this->id)
    ->where('evolutions.level','<','user_characters.level')
    ->select('user_characters.*')
    ->get();
}
```